# Pandas, getting a "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" when trying to split data

Tags: python, pandas

Have some data that looks like this:

```
Name        Best Rating
Player1     97.1% (FS)
Player2     96.3% (CB)
Player3     95.5% (DR)
Player4     95.4% (DL)
```

I am trying to split the column so that it looks like this:

```
Name        Max Rating        Best Position
Player1     97.1              FS
Player2     96.3              CB
Player3     95.5              DR
Player4     95.4              DL
```

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('prem1.csv', sep = ";", encoding = 'unicode_escape')

cols = ['Max Rating', 'Best Position']   
df['Best Rating'].str.split('% ', expand=True).rename(columns = cols)
df.head()
```

When I try this code I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Here is a more detailed explanation of the error code (screenshot).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTqwq.jpg

Any ideas with what is going wrong here and why I'm not able to split the columns?

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) requires a callable or mapper for the `columns` parameter.  Typically, a `dict` will do.

Try this instead:

```
df['Best Rating'].str.split('% ', expand=True).rename(columns = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(col)})
```

Or if you want to be more explicit:

```
cols = {0: 'Max Rating', 1: 'Best Position'}
df['Best Rating'].str.split('% ', expand=True).rename(columns = cols)
```

Result:

```
  Max Rating Best Position
0       97.1          (FS)
1       96.3          (CB)
2       95.5          (DR)
3       95.4          (DL)
```

Put it all together:

```
>>> df.drop('Best Rating', axis=1).join(df['Best Rating'].str.split('% ', expand=True).rename(columns = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(['Max Rating', 'Best Position'])}))
      Name Max Rating Best Position
0  Player1       97.1          (FS)
1  Player2       96.3          (CB)
2  Player3       95.5          (DR)
3  Player4       95.4          (DL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to split is like this:

```
In [447]: df['Max Rating'], df['Best Position'] = df['Best Rating'].str.split(' ', 1).str

In [450]: df['Max Rating'] = df['Max Rating'].str.replace('%','')

In [452]: df.drop('Best Rating', 1, inplace=True)       

In [456]: df['Best Position'] = df['Best Position'].str.replace(r'[\(\)\d]+', '')                                                                                                                           

In [457]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[457]: 
      Name Max Rating Best Position
0  Player1       97.1            FS
1  Player2       96.3            CB
2  Player3       95.5            DR
3  Player4       95.4            DL
```